# How to remove built-in quotes from variable substitution

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I have a custom variable `tabela` with values `example_table`, `example2`, `example3`. And second variable `kolumna` with values `score`, `date`, `Rising`. Those variables are used in repeat by variable rows and panels.

When I try to use following query with my MySQL data source I get an error.

```
USE server;
SELECT date, $kolumna FROM $tabela;
```

> db query error: Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT date, 'score' FROM 'example2'' at line 2

It seems like when variable is used like this: `$kolumna`, it is substituted with built-in single quotes: `'score'`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: I use this sql query:

> SELECT date, ${kolumna:csv} FROM ${tabela:csv}

and now is everything oke ;-)

Comment: Protip - do MySQL stuff in MySQL Workbench .. you can do it by hand but its like doing spreadsheet work inside of Notepad, you can do the work, but the built in validation and right clicks make it much much faster.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As [official documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/#using-variables-in-queries) states:

> From Grafana 4.7.0, template variable values are only quoted when the template variable is a multi-value.

And since your variables are multi-value (since they are used for repeat), you got built-in quoting.

Disabling of built-in quoting described [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/#disabling-quoting-for-multi-value-variables):

> To disable quoting, use the csv formatting option for variables:
>
> `${servers:csv}`

Additionally, since here on the moment of substitution variable is effectively guaranteed to have a single value, you can use `${variable:raw}`.